# Reversing Last K Elements of a Linked List - C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void LinkedList :: reverseL(int val)
{
    if (val==0 || head==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
    Node *temp=NULL;
    Node *curr=head;
    Node *bef=NULL;
    Node *aft=curr->next;
    for (int j=0; j<length()-val; j++)
    {
        temp=curr;
        curr=aft;
        aft=aft->next;
    }
    int i=0;
    while (curr!=NULL && i<val)
    {
        curr->next=bef;
        bef=curr;
        curr=aft;
        if (aft==NULL)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (aft!=NULL)
        {
            aft=aft->next;
        }
        i++;
    }
    temp->next=bef;
    }
}
```

I am just trying to figure out why I am getting a core segmentation fault for any val>=the length of the linkedlist. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

GDB shows Seg fault at temp->next=bef;
Not sure how to fix that...

Comment: A debugger will figure out the reason for you, have you tried using it?

Comment: I second the suggestion that you [step through your code in a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173).  Being able to use a debugger is a vital skill for all programmers.

Comment: Please try to learn debugging using a debugger. Debugging is a technique that not only helps you identify and address bugs, it is also an important skill to have for any programmer. Run your program using a debugger. Use gdb if that is accessible to you. It is time consuming for anyone here to go by a program where there are lots of pointer manipulation happening and one have to keep track of what was modified previously.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions I will use GDB to attempt to pinpoint the pointer error.

Comment: I usd GDB and the seg fault is from temp->next=bef; Not sure how to go about fixing it. The function is meant to reverse the last k values of a linked list.

Comment: *"GDB shows Seg fault at temp->next=bef;"* -- next step: at this point in execution, what are the values involved in this statement (`temp`, `temp->next`, and `bef`)?

Answer (score 1):

As you have found while debugging, the invalid dereferencing happens at `temp->next=bef`.

This error will happen when you call the `reverseL` method with a `val` that is equal the list's length. In that case `temp` will remain `NULL`, and thus `temp->next` is an invalid access. In this case you don't want to assign `bef` to `temp->next`, but to `head`.

So in your code replace:

```
temp->next=bef;
```

with:

```
if (temp == nullptr) {
    head = bef;
} else {
    temp->next = bef;
}
```

On a final note, in C++ you should be using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.